# Is there a way to implement show more in an Input select element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have an input select element in Bootstrap like so :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleSelect">Example select</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect">
    </select>
</div>
```

where the options are dynamically added (JQuery), the problem is that chances are the options could be of a very high number maybe 10000 options.
My question is, is it possible to make a portion of the options hidden until the user asks for them ?

Thanks.

Comment: No one "asks" to be presented with 10k options, ever. Implement an autocomplete solution or something like that instead.

Comment: To hide them when the user must see them is a bit contradictory requirement.

Comment: Hiding options using `display: none`should work with every modern browser. And if you combine it with a `:nth-child` selector, you should be able to do it by toggling a class on the select, instead of looping through all options.

Comment: I think you can get the required behavior by adding the [size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#attr-size) attribute to the `select` element.

Comment: The `size` attribute changes it from a drop down to a select list.   https://jsfiddle.net/bfn36zvd/

Comment: I'll also suggest that you consider changing to something like [tag:select2] - while being able to scroll through 10,000 options may be beneficial, if the user does know what they want, having to scroll through 10,000 options will be terrible UX.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with the help of [size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#attr-size) attribute, as per specs:

- this attribute represents the number of rows in the list that should be visible at one time.

Here is an example of how this works:

```html
<script type="module">
  import { insert } from '//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/karyon/karyon.js';


  const options = [...Array(10000)].map((n, i) =>
      ({is: 'option', content: `option: ${i}`}));
  const select = {
      is: 'select', content: options, attrs: {size: 8}
  };

  insert(select, document.body);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion from the comments would mean something like this (based on n--`s answer for generating the select field.)

It shows only the first ten options by default, and after you click the button, and open the select again, it will show all of them.

(Of course that is still not very fun to work with, from a user perspective ...)

```css
select.limited option:nth-child(n+11) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script type="module">
  import { insert } from '//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/karyon/karyon.js';


  const options = [...Array(10000)].map((n, i) =>
      ({is: 'option', content: `option: ${i}`}));
  const select = {
      is: 'select', content: options, attrs: {class: "limited"}
  };

  insert(select, document.body);
</script>
<script>
  function showAll() {
    document.querySelector('select').classList.remove('limited');
  }
</script>

<button onclick="showAll()">Show all</button>
```